How do I prevent UITableview from refreshing cell data when scrolling down?
I'm working on an iOS project and I'm facing an issue with my UITableView. I can't prevent the table view from refreshing cell data when scrolling down. I use Core Data to manage and fetch my data.
In the table view, each cell has a (+) button to add an item. Tapping this button also changes the color of the cell. However, when I scroll down, the cells refresh and their states reset, which means the color change and other dynamic states are lost.
AddShoppingItemTableViewCell:
import UIKit

// MARK: - PantryTableViewCellDelegate
protocol AddShoppingItemTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func addButtonTapped(shoppingSubItem: Shopping_Sub_List)
    func editButtonTapped(shoppingSubItem: Shopping_Sub_List)
}

class AddShoppingItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var addToListButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
    
    weak var delegate: AddShoppingItemTableViewCellDelegate?
    var shoppingSubItem: Shopping_Sub_List?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        itemNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: Global.Inter_Medium_500, size: 17.0)
        categoryLabel.font = UIFont(name: Global.Inter_Medium_500, size: 17.0)
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Action
    // add To List Button Action
    @IBAction func addToListButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let shoppingSubItem = shoppingSubItem else { return }
        addToListButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Added"), for: .normal)
        delegate?.addButtonTapped(shoppingSubItem: shoppingSubItem)
    }
    
    // edit Button Action
    @IBAction func editButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let shoppingSubItem = shoppingSubItem else { return }
        delegate?.editButtonTapped(shoppingSubItem: shoppingSubItem)
    }
    
    // MARK: Cell Configuration
    // configure The Cell
    func configureTheCell(_ shoppingSubList: Shopping_Sub_List) {
        self.shoppingSubItem = shoppingSubList
        itemNameLabel.text = shoppingSubList.name
        categoryLabel.text = "in \(shoppingSubList.category ?? "Uncategorized")"
    }
}

AddShoppingItemsVC:
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddShoppingItemsVC: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var addItemSearchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var microphoneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addShoppingItemTableView: UITableView!
    
    var shoppingList: Shopping_List?
    let coreDataHelper = CoreDataHelper()
    var allShoppingSubLists: [Shopping_Sub_List]?
    var filteredShoppingSubLists: [Shopping_Sub_List]?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        addItemSearchBar.delegate = self
        addShoppingItemTableView.delegate = self
        addShoppingItemTableView.dataSource = self
        
        addShoppingItemTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "AddShoppingItemTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
                                          forCellReuseIdentifier: Global.AddShoppingItemTableViewCellIdentifier)
        
        addShoppingItemTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "AddItemTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
                                          forCellReuseIdentifier: Global.AddItemTableViewCellIdentifier)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        
        fetchAllShoppingSubLists()
        addItemSearchBar.text = ""
        addShoppingItemTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Function
    
    // Function to fetch all shopping sub-lists
    func fetchAllShoppingSubLists() {
        if let shoppingSubLists = coreDataHelper.fetchAllShoppingSubListData() {
            self.allShoppingSubLists = shoppingSubLists.sorted { $0.name ?? "" < $1.name ?? "" }
            self.filteredShoppingSubLists = shoppingSubLists.sorted { $0.name ?? "" < $1.name ?? "" }
        } else {
            print("Error fetching shopping sub-lists")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Action
    // microphone Button Action
    @IBAction func microphoneButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("microphoneButtonAction")
    }
    
}

extension AddShoppingItemsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (filteredShoppingSubLists?.count ?? 0) + 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == (filteredShoppingSubLists?.count ?? 0) {
            // This is the last cell
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Global.AddItemTableViewCellIdentifier,
                                                        for: indexPath) as? AddItemTableViewCell {
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        } else {
            // Regular cells for shopping sub lists
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Global.AddShoppingItemTableViewCellIdentifier,
                                                        for: indexPath) as? AddShoppingItemTableViewCell {
                
                guard let shoppingSubLists = filteredShoppingSubLists?[indexPath.row] else { return cell}
                
                cell.configureTheCell(shoppingSubLists)
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 56
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
        let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Remove") { [weak self] (_, _, completionHandler) in
            self?.deleteActionForRow(at: indexPath)
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        
        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "DeleteAction")
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [editAction])
    }
    
    // edit Action For Row
    private func deleteActionForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}

// MARK: - AddShoppingItemTableViewCellDelegate
extension AddShoppingItemsVC: AddShoppingItemTableViewCellDelegate {
    func editButtonTapped(shoppingSubItem: Shopping_Sub_List) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Global.EditItemViewControllerIdentifier) as! EditItemViewController
        vc.selectedShoppingSubList = shoppingSubItem
        vc.parentList = shoppingList
        vc.isSavaItem = false
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func addButtonTapped(shoppingSubItem: Shopping_Sub_List) {
        guard let shoppingLists = shoppingList else { return }
        coreDataHelper.addShoppingSubListToItemsList(subList: shoppingSubItem, parentList: shoppingLists)
    }
}

// MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate
extension AddShoppingItemsVC: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredShoppingSubLists = allShoppingSubLists
        } else {
            filteredShoppingSubLists = allShoppingSubLists?.filter { $0.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ?? false }
        }
        addShoppingItemTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: - AddItemTableViewCellDelegate
extension AddShoppingItemsVC: AddItemTableViewCellDelegate {
    func addButtonTapped() {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Global.EditItemViewControllerIdentifier) as! EditItemViewController
        vc.isSavaItem = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}


I can't prevent UITableView from refreshing cell data when scrolling down. I use Core Data to fetch and display all shopping lists (names). When I tap the addButtonTapped, all cells have a (+) button to add an item. Tapping this button also changes the color of the cell. However, when I scroll down, the cells refresh automatically. I want to stop this from happening.

you have to save states and when refresh act according to this state...

It's how UITableViewCell works.
You need to save ui state of the call. You can make Separate UI model. And save color of the cell.
Currently you update UI element (in AddShoppingItemTableViewCell) but do not save it's state in view controller

Based on your details which you get from your model, I assumed model and create a model. In model you have to pass your key as I mention below.
struct Shopping_Sub_List {
    var name,category: String?
    //Here you need to add bool in your model to track button updated value.
    var isAdded = false
} 

AddShoppingItemTableViewCell:
func configureTheCell(_ shoppingSubList: Shopping_Sub_List) {
        self.shoppingSubItem = shoppingSubList
        itemNameLabel.text = shoppingSubList.name
        categoryLabel.text = "in \(shoppingSubList.category ?? "Uncategorized")"
    //Here you get dynamic state and based button image based on your value get.
    addToListButton.setImage(shoppingSubList.isAdded ? UIImage(named: "Added") : UIImage(named: "Add"), for: .normal)
    }


// add To List Button Action
@IBAction func addToListButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let shoppingSubItem = shoppingSubItem else { return }
    //Here you update your value and passed to the delegate.
    shoppingSubItem.isAdded = true
    addToListButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Added"), for: .normal)
    delegate?.addButtonTapped(shoppingSubItem: shoppingSubItem)
}

Using this you can get your dynamic state and mange it accordingly.
